# Lynx https patch

Tags: browser, https, patch, lynx

I have heard that there is a https patch for lynx, where can I find the patch and how would I install it? I am using a mac 10.8, I looked an GitHub and I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of Lynx – starting with [version **2.8.5**pre1](http://lynx.isc.org/current/README.ssl), released in **2004** – incorporate SSL capability natively, without requiring a source-level patch.

If you use Homebrew, you can install such a version via `brew install lynx`; if you don't use Homebrew, [use Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).